# get the href value by clicking on anchor in multiple anchors using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm trying to get the href value in multiple links or tag a.and i tried with this code

```
var val;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
        window.val = $(this).attr("href");
        alert(window.val);
    });
```

it is working fine for the multiple links and which is inside the file that is local, here few demo links

```
<a href="sometext1">a</a>
<a href="sometext2">b</a>.....
```

but problem is i want that href value globally available because i'm using that in other file . My problem is how to make it global, or is there any other way to do it.

and how to write our own function to work the same thing without using $(document).ready function.

this whole thing in one html page but i want only href value in other html page , so if we write our own js function we can use this in both html pages . And that function should return href. but here i dono how to return to $(document).ready function.

Comment: Setting a variable on the `window` is as global as it gets. Why is your code not working for you?

Comment: Are you still planning on using jQuery to set up your click-handler? If so, why do you want to get rid of the `$(document).ready()` call? You can always hook into this via a straight-up call to window.onload, but one of the nicer things about using the jQuery version is that you can add things to the ready event multiple times without overwriting, whereas I believe that each assignment to window.onload overwrites the last.

Comment: Also, when you say, "globally available" I am assuming you wish to have the value available across several pages. In this case, you need to look at a) cookies, b) localStorage, or c) sessionStorage.

Comment: this whole thing in one html page but i want only  href value in other html page , so if we write our own js function we can use this in both html pages . And that function should return href. but here i dono how to return to $(document).ready function.

Comment: Edit your question and put that info in there. Because what your question says and what your comment says are two different things.

Answer (score 5):

You can create an object-based variable:

```
var screen = {
    link:''
};
```

And then assign / access on click:

```
$('a').on('click',function(){
    screen.link = this.href;
    alert(screen.link);
});
```

I advocate this over assigning variables to the window ... a little more control this way.

Notice I used `this.href` instead of `$(this).attr('href')`. As the most interesting man in the world says, I don't always use vanilla JS, but when I do it's about 600,000 times faster.

**EDIT** So you want to get rid of `$(document).ready()` huh? Now you're venturing into the shark-infested waters of pure vanilla JS.

```
var screen = {
    link:'',
    assignLink:function(href){
        screen.link = href;
        alert(href);
    }
},
links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

if(window.addEventListener){
    for(i = links.length; i--;){
        links[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
            screen.assignLink(this.href);
        });
    }
} else {
    for(i - links.length; i--;){
        links[i].attachEvent('onclick',function(){
            screen.assignLink(this.href);
        });
    }
}
```

This is just winging it, so don't scathe me if it isn't flawless, its more to make a point. See why jQuery is so handy? All that extra crap is done in the background for you, so that you just need to deal with the burden of `$(document).ready()` and not have to deal with the rest of this kind of stuff.

**EDIT AGAIN** So ... you want to access this value across pages?

```
var screen = {
    link:((localStorage['link'] !== null) ? localSorage['link'] : ''),
    setLink:function(href){
        screen.link = href;
        localStorage['link'] = href;
        alert(href);
    },
    getLink:function(){
        return screen.link;
    }
};

$('a').on('click',function(){
    screen.setLink(this.href);
});
```

This use of localStorage is just an example ... you can get more elaborate or use cookies if you want IE7- to work, but this just providing ideas. You can set the value whenever you want using the `screen.setLink` function passing the `href`, or you can get the value whenever you want using the `screen.getLink` function.

Comment: +1 for incorporating the most interesting man in the world in to your answer :D

Comment: Does not answer what the OP really wants, see the comments.

Comment: ah yes i see what you mean @epascarello. what the OP really wants isn't something that can be done without cookies or sessionStorage, as mori57 mentions. what the OP really needs is a better fundamental understanding of how javascript works, and its limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `val` outside to make it global and you can use the val inside the function to set the href globally

```
var val;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        val = $(this).attr("href");
        alert(val);
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Somnath_k/5Rb79/1/)

Comment: Does not answer what the OP really wants

Comment: Nope, read the comments, The real question has nothing to do with an alert or global variables.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Try jQuery 1.9.1 Online</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
var val;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").on('click', function() {
        window.val = $(this).attr("href");
        alert(window.val);
        return false;
    });

    $("div").on('click', function() {
       alert (val);        
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="sometext1">a</a>
<a href="sometext2">b</a>
<div>click here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Once you click either the link a or b *val* will be set. Clicking the div tag will alert you the current reference of *val*.

Comment: Does not answer what the OP really wants.